# Maven exclusion doesn't work for jar dependency with system scope

Tags: java, maven, guava

I have a Maven multi-module project. One of the modules have jar dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thed.zephyr.connect</groupId>
    <artifactId>zfj-cloud-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <type>jar</type>
    <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/src/main/resources/zfj-cloud-rest-client-1.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar</systemPath>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This dependency has guava version 14.0.1 which conflicts with another dependency in my project with newer version of guava (27.1-jre). I'm getting the error:

```
...: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
....
```

I tried to exclude guava from jar dependency, but it seems it doesn't work this way. Any idea how can I exclude dependency from jar with system scope?

Comment: Don't exclude, add guava 27 explicitely in your own pom, it will have a priority.

Comment: @Shadov, in this case I get a new error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument".

Comment: You may have a different kind of conflict - let's say this zfj-client uses method from guava-14 that is not in guava-27 anymore (not sure if guava deletes methods). Or you have a dependency that is not a guava dependency, but also has guava classes (ye, that can happen..). Or you are running on some app serveer (websphere, weblogic etc.) - that opens a world of other possible conflicts like that.